# Can't click my mouse a few minutes after boot on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse

Right after startup, my mouse works perfectly fine (sometimes takes a few seconds to register, but good after that). However, a few minutes into using Ubuntu (has happened in both 16.04 and 14.04), the left click stops working for part of the screen.

Here's what I **can** do when this happens:

- Move the mouse anywhere on the screen.
- Keyboard works perfectly fine.
- Hover over items in the dock to the left (my list of applications).

  - Sometimes even this doesn't work, though.
- Click on items in the dock to the left and have the application launch.

  - Sometimes this fails too.
- Hover and click on items in the top menu bar for the application.
- Sometimes right clicks will be registered in the terminal, as well as being able to select text in the terminal.

Here's what I **cannot** do when this happens:

- Interact with any application on the main screen (click on links, switch to a new window, etc.)
- Select text in the active window.
- Right click in the active window.
- Scroll using the scroll wheel.

Things I've tried to resolve the issue (but none work):

- Check the power settings for my USB devices (they're all on).
- Check to make sure the mouse (Corsair M65) works on Windows (it does).
- Plug the mouse directly into the PC instead of my keyboard's USB port (no change).
- Checked my system log with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (nothing shows up).
- Listen for the mouse click event with `xev` (keyboard events show up, but mouse events do not).

The only thing that I can do to get my mouse back is to reboot.

I don't notice a trend of which this happens, but I did notice it happen one time after launching the terminal, not sure if that was related or not.

Any ideas on what I should do besides a clean Ubuntu install?

EDIT: Found something that fixes it (temporarily)! Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/588627), I have discovered that hitting `ALT + CTRL + F5` and then `ALT + F7` gives me full control over my mouse (until I lose it again). Better than nothing, but a permanent solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about the touch pad "in case this is a laptop"

Comment: @HaithamA.El-Ghareeb it's a desktop, unfortunately. If I plug in a separate mouse, the same issue happens.

Comment: I killed *compiz* using the help of *top* command. Mouse clicks started working after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that some other hardware is interfering with your mouse?

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856616/mouse-constantly-stops-working?rq=1) is another thread in which the headset seemed to cause a similar problem.

Comment: Whoa.... I have a pair of Corsair Void headphones... Any ideas on why this could be causing it? I'll go home and confirm it, but I think this should be it!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following website: http://www.c0urier.net/2016/corsair-gaming-void-usb-rgb-linux-fun.

It seems that your Corsair Void headphones may be the issue. The website gives a solution, but the tradeoff is that your volume buttons on the headphones themselves will no longer work.

Here's the important information copied from the website above.

> While I was doing some troubleshooting in the console I clicked the mute button on the headset and noticed it pasted what I had in my buffer into the console. Hmm…. Well looking at old bug reports it seemed like others had suffered from this as well. There is a work around, but you’ll unfortunately loose some functionality from the headset like turning the volume up and down, but the mute function is still working so it’s nothing that will bug me really.
>
> The fix for me was to run:
>
> lsusb
>
> Get the USB ID of the mouse and add it to xorg.conf:
>
> sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Below is his configuration. Your `MachUSB` may vary.

> ```
> Section "InputClass"
>
> Identifier "Corsair"
>
> MatchUSBID "1b1c:1b2a"
>
> Option "StartKeysEnabled" "False"
>
> Option "StartMouseEnabled" "False"
>
> EndSection
> ```

And reboot the system.

Thanks to Johnny Bravo for figuring this out.